# How to make interactive video on the webpage using HTML5?

Tags: html, video, canvas, html5-video

I have a web server with a low latency (local), what I wish to do is generate video content from the web server and allow the user to interact with that video content by clicking on the video and the click x,y will go to the server.

The location the user clicked will determine what the video will do. Also the video doesn't pause to wait for a click, it needs to continue to play.

I tried with images, to reload a single image every 50 milliseconds. On my MAC here, Chrome uses about 10% CPU usage to reload the image every 50 milliseconds where the image is generated in PHP. Well that's fairly good, ten percent is good, but I'm thinking is there a better way?

Also later I need to be able to send the XY coordinates of the user click, well I can do that with the URL.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function reloadIt() {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
  $("#topaz").attr("src", "image.php?n=" + n);
  setTimeout(reloadIt, 50);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  setTimeout(reloadIt, 50);
});

  </script>
```

Another way you could think of this problem is, how can you program a webcam client side where the user can control the camera? How do you do that with HTML5? (not Flash), so that when the user clicks up, the camera moves UP and the video changes to show it moving upwards.

Would there be any way to do video streaming like this in HTML5? Would using Canva's and streaming data to the browser help? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can create the illusion of a point-tilt camera like this**

I wasn't sure from your post if you already have the code to present a video in a canvas. If you need to know how to display video in a canvas, here is a tutorial: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

After that, assume you have an offscreen image (or video) whose source is 640x480 and a smaller canvas 320x240.

```
<img width=640 height=480>
<canvas width=320 height=480>
```

Display a **smaller part** of that image in a canvas.

```
// grab a smaller part of the source and display it in the canvas
context.drawImage(source,X,Y,source.width,source.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Then when the user clicks, just adjust which portion of the source you’re displaying

```
// change the portion of the source you’re displaying
if(mouseX<canvas.width/2 && x>0){ x-=10; }
if(mouseX>=canvas.width/2 && x<canvas.width){ x+=10; }
if(mouseY<canvas.height/2 && y>0){ y-=10; }
if(mouseY>=canvas.height/2 && y<canvas.height){ y+=10; }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3KYC5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        draw();
    }
    img.src="http://dsmy2muqb7t4m.cloudfront.net/tuts/218_Trace_Face/10B.jpg";

    var x=200;
    var y=200;
    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,canvas.width,canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      if(mouseX<canvas.width/2 && x>0){ x-=10; }
      if(mouseX>=canvas.width/2 && x<canvas.width){ x+=10; }
      if(mouseY<canvas.height/2 && y>0){ y-=10; }
      if(mouseY>=canvas.height/2 && y<canvas.height){ y+=10; }
      draw();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Click in the image to reveal in the direction of the click</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```